# Php Dropdown with rows provide from Database

Tags: php

I have a form which let's the user buy some products. I want to pass the products on a dropdown menu and I'm trying to do that with a while loop.
The thing is I'm seeing `" $row['nome'] ."` written inside the form, just like the other one. Besides that when I inspect the page, I get this part comment out :  `$query-> link`

What's seems to be not working good in the code ?
Thank you

```
<?PHP
session_start();
    $host="xxxx"; // Host name 
    $username="xxxx"; // Mysql username 
    $password="xxxx"; // Mysql password 
    $db_name="xxxxx"; // Database name 
    $tbl_name="utilizador";


    // Connect to server and select databse.
    $link = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
    mysqli_select_db($link , $db_name)or die("cannot select DB");

    // CHECK LOG IN

    if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
        echo "";

} else {
    header('Location: ../index.php');
}
    // END OF LOG IN CHECK
$link->close();

?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Formulario De Encomenda</title> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>     
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="codigoDeBarras">
        <input type="hidden" name="NIF">
        <input type="hidden" name="valorUnidade">
        <input type="hidden" name="valorTotal">
        <p>
            <label>Data</label>
            <input type="date" name="DataDeEncomenda">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Escolher Produto</label>
            <select id="produtos">
                <?php/
                    $query = $link->query("SELECT * FROM produto");
                    while ( $row = $query->fetch_array() ) {
                        echo "<option data-code=". $row['codigoDeBarras'] ." data-price=". $row['preco'] .">" $row['nome'] ."</option>";
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Escolher Fornecedor</label>
            <select id="fornecedor">
                <?php/
                    $query = $link->query("SELECT * FROM fornecedor");
                    while ( $row = $query->fetch_array() ) {
                        echo "<option data-nif=". $row['NIF'] .">". $row['nome'] ."</option>";
                    }
                ?> 
            </select>
        </p>
        <p>



            <label>Quantidade</label>
            <input type="number" min="1" name="Quantidade" value="1">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Preco(Unidade)</label>
            <span id="price">0.00</span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Valor Total</label>
            <span id="total_price">0.00</span>
        </p>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
           var codigoDeBarras = $('input[name="codigoDeBarras"]');
           var nif = $('input[name="NIF"]');
           var valorUnidade = $('input[name="valorUnidade"]');
           var valorTotal = $('input[name="valorTotal"]');
           var quantidade = $('input[name="Quantidade"]');

           $('select#produtos').change(function(){
              if( !$(this).find('option:selected').val() == '' ){
                  var price = parseInt($(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-price'));
                  var code = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-code');
                  $('#price').html(price);
                  $('#total_price').html(price * parseInt(quantidade.val()));
                  codigoDeBarras.val(code);
                  valorUnidade.val(price);
                  valorTotal.val(price * parseInt(quantidade.val()));
              }
           });
           quantidade.bind('click keyup', function(){
              if( !$('select#produtos').find('option:selected').val() == '' ){
                  var price =  $('select#produtos').find('option:selected').attr('data-price');
                  $('#total_price').html(price * parseInt($(this).val()));
                  valorTotal.val(price * parseInt(quantidade.val()));
              }
           });
           $('select#fornecedor').change(function(){
              if( !$(this).find('option:selected').val() == '' ){
                nif.val($(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-nif'));
              }
           });
        });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take a look at all the quotes inside your echo's

Comment: $row['preco'] .">" $row['nome'] -> you are missing one dot, and maybe few things more...

Comment: Already check and correct the missing dot, but no luck :|

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are missing a dot (.). Here is the code.

```
echo "<option data-code=". $row['codigoDeBarras'] ." data-price=". $row['preco'] .">" $row['nome'] ."</option>";
```

This should be written as

```
echo "<option data-code=". $row['codigoDeBarras'] ." data-price=". $row['preco'] .">". $row['nome'] ."</option>";
```

Comment: Thank you, but i already noticed and tried but still the same, showing me " $row['nome'] ." inside the field form :|

Comment: Try this way  echo "<option data-code=\"$dataArray['codigoDeBarras']\" data-price=\"$dataArray['preco']\">". $dataArray['nome']."</option>";

Answer (score 0):

Since you are mixing the HTML and PHP. You can also write like this.

```
<?php
  $query = $link->query("SELECT * FROM fornecedor");
  while ( $row = $query->fetch_array() ) { ?>
     <option data-nif="<?=$row['NIF']?>"><?=$row['nome']?></option>
  <?php
   }
?>
```

Hope this will help you.